# TextField resignFirstresponder will crash in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uitextfield

I am using `custom cell` with XIB. Now I scroll the table so the cell having the textFiled will be invisible. In this condition if i return the textField (means I call the `[textField resignFirstResponder]`) The app will crash and giving the error like

```
[UITableViewCell _didChangeToFirstResponder:]: message sent to deallocated instance
0xe05aa20.
```

Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Confirm first UITextField Delegate should not nill , set it then try , Hope it it will work

Comment: are you resigning after editing in textfiled?

Comment: from where you calling `[textField resignFirstResponder]`

Answer (score 0):

You should check couple of things:

1) In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate, when you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you should set `endEditing` to YES for this view something like:

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
[cell setEndEditing:YES];

if(!cell)
{
   // Rest of the logic goes here
}
```

2) Don't forget to set UITableViewDelegate to `self` which should represent a live class. So when delegate function calls, class exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether your TextField is first responder. If it was then you can resign it safely

**Hide Keyboard for myTextField**

```
if ([myTextField isFirstResponder]) {

    [myTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

**To resign First Responder for any subview in a view**

```
for (UIView *aSubView in self.view.subviews) {

    if ([aSubView isFirstResponder]) {

        [aSubView resignFirstResponder];

        //break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following method to resolve issue of resignFirstResponder :

```
[self resignFirstResonder:self.view];

- (BOOL)resignFirstResonder:(UIView *)textView
{
    keyBoardShow = NO;
    if(badgeHasFullInfo == YES)
    {
        if (textView.isFirstResponder)
        {
            [textView resignFirstResponder];
            return YES;
        }

        for (UIView *subView in textView.subviews)
        {
            if ([self findAndResignFirstResonder:subView])
            {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```